# CSS centering my slideshow in the header

Tags: css

I have been trying to center the slider that I have inside the header. The header and the whole container is neatly centered, with just margin: 0 auto; Then I tried to include a slideshow inside the header, and tried by many ways to place it correctly. Yes, I succeeded for my own configuration by using position:aboslute and then playing with coordinates, but that will not work for the rest of the world.

The site (under construction) is www.hrcprojectconsulting.com

Since you ll be able to see all the CSS stuff, do you know how in heaven that can be positioned? I tried all margin combinations but I am kind out of options that I could think of.

A good news is that Internet Explorer 10 is also available now for Windows 7 so, CSS3 stuff and html5 placeholders work so I ll never code for backwards things anymore.

Note: if you happen to see everything ok, this is because you have the same kind of monitor and resolution than I do.

thank you

The code for the slider:

```
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
#slider {
    width: 960px; /* important to be same as image width */
    height: 150px; /* important to be same as image height */
    position: relative; /* important */
    overflow: hidden; /* important */
}
#sliderContent {
    width: 960px; /* important to be same as image width or wider */
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px;
    left:265px;

    margin-left: 0;
}
.sliderImage {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
.sliderImage span {
    position: absolute;
    font: 10px/15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    width: 384px;
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}
```

The code for my homepage:

```
<style type = "text/css">
::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::-moz-selection {background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }



body{

    background:url('../assets/uploads/miweb/gradient2.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #4F5155;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height: 1.5em;

}

b{font-size: 110%;}
em{color: red;}

#maincontainer{
width: 960px; /*Width of main container*/
margin: 0 auto; /*Center container on page*/
}

#topsection{
background: url("../jq185/css/start/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_75_2191c0_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #2191C0;
height: 300px; /*Height of top section*/
}
```

Comment: make your header position:relative , now position you div  saay left : 10% , and width : 10% , thus both side margin are 10 % of the header in all resolutions , thus your div remains cetered

Comment: Please post the relevant code, I can't even find #slider in your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `ul` has a default padding. You will have to set the padding for your `ul#sliderContent` to 0:

```
 #sliderContent {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
 }
```

Then you should remove the `position: absolute` from your stylesheet.

To place the `sliderContent` at the bottom you could do like this:

```
 #topsection {
    position: relative;
 }
 #slider {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
 }
 #sliderContent {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
 }
```

Comment: @user1815822 - The images seems to be to small? To place the slideshow further down you could set `margin-top` of the `sliderContent`.

Comment: @user1815822 - That was because you set position absolute on `sliderContent` and not `slider`, sorry about that. Recheck the answer.

Comment: Krister, In my screen it went ok automatically, how do you view it? and what screen size and resolution do you have?

Comment: @user1815822 - The screen size shouln't matter in this case.

Comment: thank you, I view it in several computers even very old ones, it works well. With regards to the picture being too small and having been stretched out, yes, it is not the picture to stay, it was just to fill the place i did it on the fly, it is about a car, nothing to do with the web. Thank you very much for your help and solution